# How to declare a custom library in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am going through a code which uses a custom library. But i am unable to see the content of the library. Also, I want to know exactly how was this library created. It is for an actel FPGA A42, and the developer has named the library as a42.all. The tool sused is Libero IDE

Comment: Your question is unclear. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries "A *design library* is an implementation-dependent storage facility for previously analyzed design units." Creating libraries is implementation (tool) dependent. A library clause make a library logical name (an identifier) associated with an implementation library visible.  A library logical name isn't an expanded name (with the suffix **all**, 8.3 Selected names), **all** can appear in use clauses (12.4 Use clauses, 13.4 Context clauses). To (re-)analyze or view a library's design units you'd need their VHDL source.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries are created in the tool, not VHDL itself.
For example, in modelsim, libraries are created with the vlib command, eg.

```
vlib my_library;
```

In VHDL you can include your library in any region with the library command, and objects (eg package) can be included with the use command:

```
library my_library;
use my_library.some_package.all;
```

Comment: Thanks...the tool is Libero IDE. Is there any way I could see a custom library(details of the library) using the Libero IDE tool?

Comment: @rubana Yes, almost certainly. Read the instructions to find out how to do it. (I'm not saying that to be unhelpful. I do have access to Libero, but it would be a bit of hassle to get it set up. Then I'd have to read the instructions.)